# La función no esta definida en JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema en JAVASCRIPT ya que realice un archivo externo con una función que al presionar la opción de un menú me redirecciona a una pagina, al llamar la función en el evento onclick hago referencia a mi función que esta en el JS externo pero me marca el navegador que no esta definida, mi archivo JS se llama eventosJS.js que incluyo pero no me detecta la funcion

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function myFunction(url) {

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img src='../Images/cargando1.gif' height='50px' width='50px'/><br/>Un momento por favor...</center>");
        $("#muestraInicio").hide();
      },

      success: function(response) {
        $("#muestraSeccion").html(response).hide().fadeIn('fast');
      },
      error: function(xhr, error) {

          if (xhr.status === 0) {
            return ($("#mensajeError").html("<center>No conectado.\nPor favor verifica tu conexión a la red.</center>"));
          } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
            return ($("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img src='../Images/error404.png' width='500px' height='350px' class='img img-responsive'/></center>").hide().fadeIn('slow'));
          } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
            return ($("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img src='../Images/error500.png' width='500px' height='350px' class='img img-responsive'/></center>").hide().fadeIn('slow'));
          } else if (error === 'parsererror') {
            return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Falló la conversión JSON.</center>'));
          } else if (error === 'timeout') {
            return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Error time out.</center>'));
          } else if (error === 'abort') {
            return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Peticion Ajax cancelada.</center>'));;
          } else {
            return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Uncaught Error.\n' + xhr.responseText + '</center>'));
          }
        }
        //complete: function () { $("#divCargandoFormAdmin").fadeOut('slow'); }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>@PageData("Title")</title>
  @RenderSection("head", required:=False)

  <link href="../Content/misEstilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../Scripts/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
  <script src="../Scripts/eventosJs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="padding:5px">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            <span style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px orange;">
                            <img src="../Images/logof.png" width="60px" height="30px" style="margin-top: -10px;" /></a></span>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('registro.html')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Registrar Factura</a>
            </li>

            <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('Almacen.html')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Registrar Series</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <!-- opciones parte izquierda-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../cerrarSesion">Cerrar sesión <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="maximoPagina">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: el desarrollo que realizas es asp.net mvc ?

Comment: 1. Saca el `$(document).on('ready', ...)` y solo deja la función.
2. Los scripts **por lo general** siempre deben ir antes del cierre del body, para menorar carga y mejorar tiempos de respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que es una función lo que estás utilizando, no es necesario que la incluyas en el método `ready()`, este es más apropiado para ejecutar algo o agregar un listener, entre otros tantos usos, pero es menos interesante para definir una función que será llamada con un evento inline.

De hecho estás definiendo una función dentro de otra función.

Una solución entonces es:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // otro código que necesite esperar que el DOM esté cargado totalmente
});


function myFunction(url) {

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img src='../Images/cargando1.gif' height='50px' width='50px'/><br/>Un momento por favor...</center>");
    $("#muestraInicio").hide();
  },

  success: function(response) {
    $("#muestraSeccion").html(response).hide().fadeIn('fast');
  },
  error: function(xhr, error) {

      if (xhr.status === 0) {
        return ($("#mensajeError").html("<center>No conectado.\nPor favor verifica tu conexión a la red.</center>"));
      } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
        return ($("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img src='../Images/error404.png' width='500px' height='350px' class='img img-responsive'/></center>").hide().fadeIn('slow'));
      } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
        return ($("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img src='../Images/error500.png' width='500px' height='350px' class='img img-responsive'/></center>").hide().fadeIn('slow'));
      } else if (error === 'parsererror') {
        return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Falló la conversión JSON.</center>'));
      } else if (error === 'timeout') {
        return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Error time out.</center>'));
      } else if (error === 'abort') {
        return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Peticion Ajax cancelada.</center>'));;
      } else {
        return ($("#mensajeError").html('<center>Uncaught Error.\n' + xhr.responseText + '</center>'));
      }
    }
    //complete: function () { $("#divCargandoFormAdmin").fadeOut('slow'); }
});
};
```

Comment: Ok si lo intente asi hace unos minutos y si funciono

Answer (score 3):

Si haces uso del Developer Tools del browser (al cual accedes con F12) podrias validar (usando la solapa network) si el .js se esta resolviendo correctamente.

Lo que recomendaria es que definas `~/`

```
<script src="~/Scripts/eventosJs.js"></script>
```

de esta forma la referencia al .js se realiza desde el root del sitio y no tendra problemas para incluirlo cuando carga la pagina.

Cuando definas una funcion no lo ubiques dentro de ready() de jquery, este solo aplicaria a la asignacion de eventos en tags.
O sea si defines

```
$(function() {

  $('li .active').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'POST',
          ...

   });

  });
```

en donde el onclick del `li` lo eliminas alli si va dentro del ready() que en versiones mas nuevas solo debes definir

```
$(function(){ ...
```

no hay falta pones el document ni el ready()